# Silverlight Won't Show Exceptions

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception, silverlight-4.0

I'm working on a project in Silverlight and somewhere an exception is thrown. I'm not concerned with fixing the exception... I just want to find it.

Instead of Visual Studio popping up and showing the the line where the exception happened, I instead get a little window labeled "Just In Time" which mentions an error 4004, a managed runtime error. It asks which debugger I want to use to solve the problem. But, it only provides one option: a *new* instance of Visual Studio. If I try to accept its proposal, the new instance complains that a debugger is already attached.

Why doesn't the instance of VS which built the program and is already running catch the exception and show me where it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is strange behavior.  The first thing I would do is change a few settings

- Disable Just My Code
- Enable native debugging
- Break on first exception thrown

This should help you narrow down the place where the exception is occuring.

Disable Just My Code

- Tools -> Options
- Debugger
- Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"

Enable Native Debugging

- Right click on the project and select properties
- Go to the Debug Tab
- Check "Enable Unmanaged Debugging"

Break on first exception thrown

- Debug -> Exceptions
- Check "Throws" for Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Comment: @Stefan I added steps for each of the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has a habbit of swallowing exceptions. I call this "silent failure" and have found it very expensive and frustrating. When working with Silverlight do everything you can do expose exceptions, e.g. binding failures.

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189070%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Also there is a setting on elements to have them visualise binding failures but I forget what it is as I'm not working in Silverlight any more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the type of debugging. In your project properties make sure you enable Silverlight debugging. In your website project right click, go to properties, then on the 'Web' tab at the bottom there's a section called Debuggers. Make sure that Silverlight is selected.

Sometimes the JS debugger is attached to the IE process, which means that there's a debugger attached, but it's simply not the debugger you want. I think this might be the cause of this problem.

Hope this helps. 
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

click debug, choose exceptions, mark common language runtime exceptions as thrown. 
I had the same problem and it fixed the problem for me